# docker-py: attach to network before starting the container

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy, docker-network

Until recently, I could attach a container to a network before starting the container as follows:

```
params = {
    'image': 'busybox',
    'name': 'test',
}
result = docker_client.create_container(**params)
docker_client.connect_container_to_network(result['Id'], network_id)
docker_client.start(result['Id'])
```

However, now I always get an error, because the container has not been started when I'm connecting it to the network:

```
APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("Container 0b1005fc86be565d1a54c44f89f2a60d338b541f8b73805c2a367116bf04a060 is not running")
```

I can reproduce the same error with the command-line client:

```
% docker create --name test busybox
7aa04b908b2ec45a37f272809ec909116cfae5ae80a13c6596822ca4d9b39a0e
% docker network connect test 7aa04b908b2e
Error response from daemon: Container 7aa04b908b2ec45a37f272809ec909116cfae5ae80a13c6596822ca4d9b39a0e is not running
```

So I need to connect the container to the network directly when I create the container:

```
% docker create --net=test busybox test
```

In `docker-py`, how do I attach a container to a network directly during creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [HostConfig](http://docker-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/hostconfig/) to configure the network the container is attached to:

> `network_mode` is available since v1.11 and sets the Network mode for the container ('bridge': creates a new network stack for the container on the Docker bridge, 'none': no networking for this container, 'container:[name|id]': reuses another container network stack, 'host': use the host network stack inside the container or any name that identifies an existing Docker network).

As an example, you would run:

```
params = {
    'image': 'busybox',
    'name': 'test',
    'host_config': docker_client.create_host_config(network_mode='test')
}
docker_client.create_container(**params)
```

This connects the container to the network `test`.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
host_config = client.create_host_config(
    network_mode='my-net'
)
networking_config = client.create_networking_config({
    'my-net': client.create_endpoint_config(
    )
})
container = client.create_container(
    image='josepainumkal/vwadaptor:jose_toolUI',
    host_config=host_config,
    networking_config = networking_config
)
```